# Where I did something wrong? error while execution (runtime error)

Tags: c#, winforms

Where I did something wrong; I'm getting an error:
in this line:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray, icondirentry.ImageOffset, (Array)
                 iconFile.iconImage[index], 0, icondirentry.BytesInRes);
```

> Error: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Complete code of this method is:

```
 public static IconClass.IconFile FromFile(string filename)
      {
        IconClass.IconFile iconFile = new IconClass.IconFile();
        byte[] numArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc((object) numArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        iconFile.iconDir = (IconClass.ICONDIR) Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof (IconClass.ICONDIR));
        iconFile.iconEntry = new IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY[checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count - 1 )];
        iconFile.iconImage = new byte[checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count - 1)][];
        int num1 = Marshal.SizeOf((object) iconFile.iconDir);
        Type type = typeof (IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY);
        int num2 = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
        int num3 = 0;
        int num4 = checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count - 1);
        int index = num3;
        while (index <= num4)
        {
          IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY icondirentry = (IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY) Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(checked (gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + (long) num1)), type);
          iconFile.iconEntry[index] = icondirentry;
          iconFile.iconImage[index] = new byte[checked (icondirentry.BytesInRes - 1 )];
          Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray, icondirentry.ImageOffset, (Array) iconFile.iconImage[index], 0, icondirentry.BytesInRes);
          checked { num1 += num2; }
          checked { ++index; }
        }
        gcHandle.Free();
        return iconFile;
      }
```

Comment: `icondirentry.BytesInRes - 1 + 1`, I'm sorry, but what?

Comment: And what is `IconClass.IconFile`? There's a huge amount of relevant code that we just have no idea about...

Comment: @PakkuDon What you suggest?

Comment: icondirentry.BytesInRes - 1 + 1????  how about icondirentry.BytesInRes - 0 instead?  lol...

Comment: @PakkuDon and Jon Skeet; Sorry a bit mistake while putting the code where the error occurred I just changed it now,
if You can help me please

Comment: @TMcKeown error is not in -1 +1. please have a look at the line where error occurred.
If you people suggest me to use -1 in code, Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Array) iconFile.iconImage[index]
```

Check if index is not higher than the size of IconImage (array, list or whatever it is) members.

Comment: @Xorraxx _"My intent is to change Icon of an exe file"_ - Why do you want to do that?  Sounds a bit dubious to me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem...
Courtesy to Niraj Doshi...
Thanks Niraj Doshi.

here is the code:

```
public static IconClass.IconFile FromFile(string filename)
  {
    IconClass.IconFile iconFile = new IconClass.IconFile();
    byte[] numArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc((object) numArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    iconFile.iconDir = (IconClass.ICONDIR) Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof (IconClass.ICONDIR));
    iconFile.iconEntry = new IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY[checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count + 1 )];
    iconFile.iconImage = new byte[checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count + 1)][];
    int num1 = Marshal.SizeOf((object) iconFile.iconDir);
    Type type = typeof (IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY);
    int num2 = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
    int num3 = 0;
    int num4 = checked ((int) iconFile.iconDir.Count-1);
    int index = num3;
    while (index <= num4)
    {
      IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY icondirentry = (IconClass.ICONDIRENTRY) Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(checked (gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + (long) num1)), type);
      iconFile.iconEntry[index] = icondirentry;
      iconFile.iconImage[index] = new byte[checked (icondirentry.BytesInRes + 1)];
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray, icondirentry.ImageOffset, (Array) iconFile.iconImage[index], 0, icondirentry.BytesInRes);
      checked { num1 += num2; }
      checked { ++index; }
    }
    gcHandle.Free();
    return iconFile;
  }
```

problem was with indexes passed to process.